# iPhone posting to facebook app wall

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my iPhone app I only want to post a message to a Facebook App page.

I have downloaded and implemented the facebook-sdk and I have looked at the demo-app.

What I have read is that It looks like that I have to do three things:
- login to facebook (done!)
- get an access token
- post the message (Is this the same as posting to my own wall)

Is using the graph-api's the right track?

Can anyone help me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

may be this solve your problem

```
- (void) SendTextMsg
{
  NSMutableDictionary *param = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:param andDelegate:self];
}
```